# Matrix traversal with rules that must hit certain cells. Interview

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, traversal

There is a matrix which contains white cells , black cells and only one gray cell, need to go from (0,0) to (N-1, N-1) if Arra[N][N] 
constraints: 
a. The path should cover only white cells and should go via grey cell. 
b. The node once visited cannot be visited again.

White cells are represented by 0, black cells by 1 and grey cell by 2.

Based on my research, BFS won't work. I am not sure how to get DFS to work on this problem. Some people suggested A* search, but I am not sure how to deploy it here. Some suggest that first find the shortest path to grey cell, then from grey cell we find the shortest path to N-1, N-1. But I believe this will not work in some cases where the shortest path to grey cell blocks the path from grey cell to destination cell. For instance,

```
-1 => start 
-2 => destination
0 => white space
1 => black space
2 => grey space

-1 0 0 0 0 
0  0 0 1 0 
0  1 0 2 0 
0  1 1 1 1 
0  0 0 0 -2
```

The solution to this is to take the longer path (from source to right edge of square, down to 2's row, then to 2) to grey cell, and then go from there to destination.

Java please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small problem like yours, DFS should be good enough. Just walk in all four directions from your current point. Return immediately if you hit a wall, step off the matrix or re-visit a cell. Before leaving a cell, mark it as visited. (And don't forget to clear that flag before you return, so that other branches can use that cell.)

That will give you all possible paths, not only the shortest. Of course, you have to keep track of the path, so that you can do something with it when you reach the destination. You also have to keep track of whether you passed the grey square and consider only valid paths when reaching the destination.

**Edit**: In pseudocode, the algorithm looks like this:

```
traverse(curr, dest, path, pass):
    # curr: current cell
    # dest: destination cell
    # path: path, ie list of cells up to now
    # pass: have we passed the grey cell?

    # stop recursion short
    if curr is out of bounds: return
    if curr is impassable: return
    if curr is visited: return

    # treat cell as visited and add to path
    mark curr as visited
    path = path + [curr]
    if curr is grey: pass = true

    if curr is dest:
        if pass: add path to solution
    else:
        traverse(adj(curr, N), dest, path, pass)
        traverse(adj(curr, E), dest, path, pass)
        traverse(adj(curr, W), dest, path, pass)
        traverse(adj(curr, S), dest, path, pass)

    # clean up athis path for other recursions
    mark curr as not visited
    path = path[:-1]
```

You start off the search with:

```
traverse(start, dest, [], false)
```

Where it says `add path to solution`, it depends on what you want. You could just print the path (and maybe abort the recursion with an exception), you could add it to a global list of solutions, you could pass another list to the function and add it to this list. The function `adj(cell, dir)` returns an adjacent cell; that's just a fancy way of saying something like `(x, y + 1)`.

You asked for a solution in Java, which I'm not familiar with, so I can't give you any practical advice here. The cell coordinates should probably be tuples, the path should be a vector of cells, whether a cell was visited could be checked in a set. You know your Java data structures better than I do.

Comment: How do we return the distinct path for each recursive call and verify which path is valid?

Comment: @Kelvin: You can keep the coordinates of the visited cells in a separate vector. Alternatively, you could add a `next` field to your cells, which is valid for the path in the current iteration. Additionally, you have to keep a flag that says whether you have visited the grey field or not. The current path and that flag belong to the state of the recursion. Note that this method finds all possible paths, because it does not use the optimisations of shortest-path algorithms. Also, it will be slow for mazes with vast open space. For your problem, ths method is okay, however.

Comment: If we mark visited node off, then it would block other recursions from trying all possibilities, wouldnt it? If we do

Comment: If we mark visited node off, then it would block other recursions from trying all possibilities, wouldnt it? If we do
hashMap<Cell, Cell> prev = hashMap<Cell, Cell>();
recursion(prev, something); // 1
recursion(prev, something2); // 2
return prev;
and say both recursion1 and recursion2 add a Cell to the map, but I only want the node got from recursion1, not recursion2, how should I do that? Say if a valid solution is found by doing what you suggested, and how should it recursively go back and tell the caller which path is valid?

Comment: @Kelvin: I've added pseudocode that hopefully shows you the workings of the algorithm. The easiest way to keep track of the path is to add the current cell to a list and then do something with that list when you reach your destination.

Comment: The information whether a cell has been visited and the current path are valid only for the current recursion. The number of cells in the path and the number of visited paths are always equal to the recursion depth. In my solution above, I append the cell to the path, recuser, then remove it again so that other (sibling) recursions can visit that cell again. You could also pass copies to which the cell is added to the recusive call, but you would end up with quite a bunch of copied vectors.

Comment: @M Oehm: Thanks for your pseudocode. It is very helpful. When we 'mark curr as visited',how do we make sure this won't affect other recursions so that they will still see this node as unvisited? Marking a node visited will probably use a hashmap I believe. 
'add path to solution' will work if we just print it out or copy it to a passed in argument, but what if we were to return it as a list? How do we ensure the caller will get the valid list, not the one from other recursions?
Lastly, could you plz explain "# clean up athis path for other recursions mark curr as not visited path = path[:-1] '

Comment: Visited could be a hashmap, yes. Note that the node gets marked as unvisited before returning from the routine so that other branches can still visit ist. The Python-like syntax `path[:-1]` means the list without its last element. Java implementations might have `pop` or `pop_back` to remove the last item, I don't know. Instead of returning a list, you should pass a list as parameter by reference, so that you can add to it and have a complete list after all recursions are done. (And "athis" should be "this", of course.)

Comment: I thought the fact that hashmap is passed by reference means that any changes from any level of recursion will be visible to all recursions. Could you please explain why we need to mark the curr as unvisited and remove the curr from path? I know you mentioned it is for other sibling recursions to be able to visit that cell again, but I don't visually see it...

Comment: The changes will be visible to all recursions until you revert them. Imagine your starting point (0, 0). You go east, then south, then further into the maze. Cell (1, 1) is now visited. Eventually, recursion of this path returns. You are now back at cell (0, 0) and go first south, then east. This is, of course, a valid move, because the visit to (1, 1) was in another recursion. (I called it "sibling" recursion, because it starts from the same (grand-)parent, namely cell (0, 0).) You can think of the algorithm as probing the maze step by step, and then undoing these steps when you are done.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense. If we have found the valid path, how do we return it to the top-most parent, which is the very original caller at starting point (0,0). Since we call four recursion each time, how do we check each returned list is the right one without using a global variable. Because you mentioned 'add path to solution', it sounds like adding the path to a global variable. Can we return the result without making use of it? Also, I still don't get why we need to mark the node unvisited and take it off the list in the end.

Comment: I just wrote some code to test. Without the last part of your code (# clean up this path for other recursions), other recursions were able to see the changes done by other non-sibling recursions. Looks like cleaning up at the end of the code is the way to make sure only siblings can see the changes done by recursions in the same path. However, I still haven't figured out how to return the result except saving it to a passed in argument or a global variable.

Comment: @Kelvin: This is getting needlessly long. I've answered most of your questions in previous comments, please reread them. Your problem is small enough that you can simulate the algorithm with pencil and quad paper. See what happens when you don't mark nodes as unvisited when you return from the recursive function.

Comment: @Kelvin: If you want a single result or the shortest, return the list of visited cells when reaching the destination. If you hit a dead end, pass a dummy value, maybe an empty list ot a null value. When you spread the path into four subpaths for the cardinal directions, only keep the best path from these calls, i.e. the shortest one that is not null. Return that, it will be passed down to your starting point, if there arent any better paths found in "sibling" recursions.

Comment: @M Oehm: Thank you very much. It helps a lot. I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a min cost max flow problem. Model your matrix as a graph where you have an edge of cost 1 and capacity 1 between each connected cells and run a min cost max flow algorithm on the resulting graph.

Of course, since the cost is 1 for each edge, the problem reduces to just a max flow problem, which can be solved by [Edmonds - Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

Comment: What ensures that the path goes through the grey cell with this approach?

Comment: I assume you just meant [min cost flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cost_flow_problem), not min cost *max* flow, but I'm with Peter on this one.

Comment: If you find the min cost of a flow of 2 from both the start and the end (or perhaps just starting from a new vertex pointing to both) to the grey cell, that should work.

Comment: @Dukeling - Thanks for your comment, that helped me a lot to understand this approach. I think it is a really neat idea to use the grey cell as the sink and the start/end as the sources, +1

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with A*? The idea is pretty simple.

As your initial list, you only have the white cells. Then you let A* figure out the way from start to your grey cell. Once it has found the path, you do the same from the grey cell to the end but not only remove the black cells from your list but also those, where you already went.

However, I am not going to implement A* for you. Have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star) and [this A* Java implementation](http://code.google.com/p/a-star-java/source/browse/AStar/src/aStar/AStar.java?r=7).

Also note that A* might be overkill, because all steps have the same weight it might be better to consider an algorithm that does take that into account.

Comment: What's wrong with A* in this example is that the shortest path from the starting point to the grey cell blocks all possibilities to reach the destination using only unvisited cells. Maybe you could use A* from destination to start when the first A* doesn't give you a valid path.

Comment: uh, yeah. You are right. You could also use A* to find the path from the grey cell to the destination.

Comment: Sorry, I meant paths from destination to start _via_ the grey cell, of course, i.e. do the same with start and destination swapped. (I don't know whether there are deadlock mazes that obstruct the path via the grey cell in both directions.)

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode assuming that you have some way to generate *all* paths from one point to another avoiding obstacles:

```
for path1 in each path from start to grey:
  if exists path2 from grey to finish when path1 is no-go:
    return concatenation of path1 and path2
return nothing
```